# How can I fix the '401 Unauthorized' error when using Carte API to retrieve jobs and transformations?

Tags: repository, kettle, http-status-code-401, http-status-code-302

I am trying to retrieve the list of jobs and transformations using the carte API REST. However I am not able. From code, when executing `http://...../kettle/status` I get a **200** code, but If I try to access `http://...../kettle/jobs` I get an error.

If I execute the following command:

`wget http://cluster:cluster@localhost:8080/kettle/status`

I get the following response:

```
--2023-05-25 13:38:50-- http://cluster:*password*@localhost:8080/kettle/status
Resolviendo localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1, ::1
Conectando con localhost (localhost)[127.0.0.1]:8080... conectado.
PeticiÃ³n HTTP enviada, esperando respuesta... 401 Unauthorized
Reutilizando la conexiÃ³n con localhost:8080.
PeticiÃ³n HTTP enviada, esperando respuesta... 302 Found
LocalizaciÃ³n: http://localhost:8080/kettle/status/ [siguiendo]
--2023-05-25 13:38:50--  http://localhost:8080/kettle/status/ Reutilizando la conexiÃ³n con localhost:8080.
```

Can you guess where the problem is?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Replying to the below questions:

> I am trying to retrieve the list of jobs and transformations using the carte API REST. However I am not able. From code, when executing http://...../kettle/status I get a 200 code, but If I try to access http://...../kettle/jobs I get an error.

In order to retrieve the status of the Jobs and Transformations from Pentaho Carte, you need to use `/kettle/jobStatus/` and  `/kettle/transStatus/` REST endpoints to correctly fetch the results. The Pentaho documents provides the necessary details on the same.

- [Pentaho Carte Job Status](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/Data_Integration_and_Analytics/9.5/Developer_center/REST_API_Reference/Carte/030#GETjobStatus)
- [Pentaho Carte Transformation Status](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/Data_Integration_and_Analytics/9.5/Developer_center/REST_API_Reference/Carte/020#GETtransStatus)

In both of the above situations you are required to pass the Job / Transformation name or object id's in order to fetch the details.

> If I execute the following command:
> wget http://cluster:cluster@localhost:8080/kettle/status
> I get the following response:

Assuming the username and password are correct for the carte server, it seems the logs generated are the default behaviour of WGET. WGET generates a lot of diagnostics information that may seem like getting redirected to the stdout whereas the errors are pushed to stderr. WGET also interprets the response headers as part of diagnostic information. So, it’ll be sending the header information to stderr. In order to solve this, you can use the arg, `-q` (quiet) to suppress the diagnostic information. [Blog here for ref.](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/wget-document-and-headers-to-stdout#:%7E:text=The%20wget%20command%20outputs%20the,directs%20the%20content%20to%20stdout.&text=Great!) For example:

```
wget -q 'http://localhost:8085/kettle/status/?xml=Y' --user cluster --password cluster  --output-document kettle_status
```

[image]

The above command redirects the output to a file `kettle_status`. `xml=Y` generates and XML output of the Carte REST API response.

Alternatively, you can use **CURL** to get the kettle status in an XML format.

```
 curl -u "cluster:cluster" -X GET 'http://localhost:8084/kettle/status/?xml=Y'
```

Read in details about Working with [Pentaho Carte Servers using this blog post](https://tech-spaghetti.com/2023/12/02/working-with-pentaho-carte-server/).

[image]